# How to query rows with one matching and one non-matching field

Tags: mysql, sql

Given `tblAllKeys(fldKey, fldCode)` and `tblModKeys(fldKey, fldCode)` with data in `tblAllKeys` of...

```
fldCode   fldKey
dba       1
dba       2
dba       3
dba       4
cde       1
cde       2
cde       3
```

in `tblModKeys` ...

```
fldCode   fldKey
dba       1
dba       2
dba       3
dba       4
dba       5
dba       6
cde       1
cde       2
cde       3
cde       4
```

I want to return the the rows from tblModKeys where fldCode matches with tblAllKeys.fldCode but where tblModKeys.fldKey does not exist in tblAllKeys.fldCode. I am interested to know if there is a way to do this with a join specifically?

Comment: `left join on a.fldcode=b.fldcode and b.fldkey is null`?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3cea And effort was saved.

Comment: Do you mean "`tblmodKeys.fldKey` does not exist in `tblAllKeys.fldKey`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT mk.*
FROM tblModkeys mk
JOIN tblAllkeys ak1 ON mk.fldcode = ak1.fldcode -- fldcode exists in tblAllkeys
LEFT JOIN tblAllkeys ak2 ON mk.fldkey = ak2.fldkey
WHERE ak2.fldkey IS NULL -- fldkey does not exist in tblAllkeys
```

Comment: Joining against `tblAllKeys` twice is more elegant, more straight forward, probably easier optimized, and I dare say it _should_ be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, but your sample data does not do it justice.  You need an example of a row like `fgh, 5` in the mod keys table that is not in the all keys table.

The idea is to use `left outer join`, but only on the `fldcode` column.  That way, you can check if there is no match to this code.  Then do an aggregation to look for a match on `fldkey`;

```
select mk.*
from tblModkeys mk left outer join
     tblAllkeys ak
     on mk.fldcode = ak.fldcode
group by mk.fldcode, mk.fldkey
having sum(ak.fldkey = mk.fldkey) = 0 and sum(ak.fldcode is null) = 0;
```